# Can't connect to oracle XE DB

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames

So I copied an running VM with openSUSE. When I started the machine I did `lsnrctrl start` like always and then everything worked. Usually I got the following output then:

```
# lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 11-AUG-2015 19:46:46

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                11-AUG-2015 19:46:43
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/lpdev/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
#
```

my XE instance was cooming up much later. But then later XE came up and like I said, everything worked fine. Now I did the same, but my XE Service is not cooming up.

```
lpdev:~ # tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 11-AUG-2015 19:53:05

Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = xe)))
OK (0 msec)
lpdev:~ #
```

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xe)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

sqlplus output:

```
lpdev:~ # sqlplus lp@xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Aug 11 19:58:14 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

When running my perl script I get:

```
AH01215: DBI connect('XE','username',...) failed: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach) at /srv/www/cgi-bin/lib/myfunctions.pm line 372., referer: http://192.168.0.13/
```

I have no clue what is going on here, can anyone help me quickly please? Need to finish some stuff :/

Comment: You can encourage the DB to register if it starts after the listener, though it should sort itself out after a while, with [`alter system register`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF53142). If it will register with your new listener but still won't with the old one, check the `local_listener` parameter and if set whether a hostname it refers to resolves to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what the hell went wrong, I'm using this VM for close a year now. Anyway, depressed as I'm now, I just created a new listener.ora using http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sample_listener_ora_files.htm. Everything seems to work for now.